# What do you mean by scaling a vector in a particular direction?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Find a 2 × 2 matrix $A$ such that the linear transformation $T : R^2 → R^2$
defined by $T(~u) =A~u$ geometrically scales by a factor of 2 in the direction of the vector $\left(1,2\right)^T$ and scales by the factor of -3 in the direction of $\left(-1,1\right)^T$.

Above is the question I'm trying to solve. I don't understand what the question means when it says "scales by a factor *in a particular direction.*"

Any help in understanding this would really help!

Comment: Scaling means multiplying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means $T(a(1,\,2)^T+b(-1,\,1)^T)=2a(1,\,2)^T-3b(-1,\,1)^T$.

Comment: What are a and b here? I still don't get what the transformation is doing here...

Comment: They're arbitrary scalars.

Answer (score 0):

It says that $(1,2)^t$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $2$ and $(-1,1)^t$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-3$. Since you have the eigenvectors and eigenvalues you can readily express $A$ in its diagonalized form.